# Mod_Rewrite no CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, apache, htaccess, url-amigável

Preciso alterar todas as URL's de um site, depois de pronto.

A URL atual está na seguinte estrutura: ***www.meudominio.com.br/site/***
E gostaria que fosse removida, de todas as urls internas, a pasta site, sem ter que mexer na estrutura de arquivos.

Outra alteração é mais delicada:

```
www.meudominio.com.br/site/Produtos/view/13
```

para

```
www.meudominio.com.br/nome-do-produto-ou-da-noticia
```

Estudei e testei alguns códigos do mod_rewrite do .HTACCESS mas não consegui resolver a situação. Tentei também pelo Routes:: do CakePHP, também sem êxito.

### .HTACCESS:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^site/Home http://www.meudominio.com.br/ [L]
RewriteRule ^site/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) http://www.meudominio.com.br/ [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).*$ http://www.meudominio.com.br/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Primeira coisa, você não precisa deixar su site na pasta `site`. Segunda coisa, posta as tentativas que você fez no routes do cake pra ver se existe algo que você tenha feito errado. Terceira coisa, se possível descreva o comportamento que ocorreu nas suas tentativas.

Comment: Meu HTACCESS:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^site/Home http://www.meudominio.com.br/ [L]
RewriteRule ^site/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) http://www.meudominio.com.br/ [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).*$ http://www.meudominio.com.br/$2 [L]

Comment: Existem outras pastas no seu `public_html` que te impeçam de deixar os arquivos do cake na pasta raiz? Quais foram suas tentativas usando as rotas do cakephp?

Comment: Nenhuma pasta, mas meu receio é desconfigurar algo no site.

Comment: Quanto às rotas, tentei inserir um Routes::connect no arquivo routes, e gerar o link na view via $this->HTML->link - mas parece que redirecionou todas as páginas de estrutura para o controller indicado, e não somente ele.


Router::connect('/:titulo', 
    array('controller' => 'NaMidia', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('titulo'),
        'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-]+')
 );

Comment: Se não há outras pastas não há problema em mover seu arquivos pra pasta raiz. Você já leu na [**documentação do Cake**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) como lidar com Rotas?